# Loading a page but not into a container div using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a drop down that I select a file type from, I then want it to fire at a page that generates a file depending on what was selected and forces a download of it using `header` in php. Here's the jQuery.

```
$('#exportdropdown').change(function(){
var searchinput = $('#searchinput').val();
var maxrec = $('#navdropdown option:selected').text();
    $('.loadCont').fadeIn();
    if($('#importbutton').hasClass('clickedButton')){
        $.get('export.php', {filter: 'import', maxrecords: maxrec, type: 'xls'});
    }else{
        $.get('export.php', {filter: 'export', maxrecords: maxrec, type: 'xls'});
    }
    $('.loadCont').delay('600').fadeOut();
});
```

I'm forcing the type at the moment for testing, but it doesn't seem to work how I expected. When you address the file with the data below so `export.php?filter='import'&maxrecords=15&type='xls'` it forces the download fine. Just not using the jQuery method. Anything obvious that stands out to someone more experienced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax is pointless here, all you are doing is requesting a link which pushes a file to your browser. Try:

```
window.location.href = "export.php?filter=" + filter + "&maxrecords=" + maxrecords + "&type=" + type;
```

Comment: agreed, excepting that maxrec is coming from user input, so it needs encodeURI applied :)

Answer (score 0):

In few of my projects I am doing something similar but quite differently :).

On dropdown click I would open new window and there executed karim79 code (on body load for example).
SO

> 1. click on dropdown item
> 2. open new window with appropriate parameters     something like:

```
    window.open ("newindow.html?filter=" + filter + "&maxrecords=" + maxrecords + "&type=" +  type"); 
//this is not tested, but you got the point
```

> 1. on body's onload event execute either:

```
window.location.href = "export.php?filter=" + filter + "&maxrecords=" + maxrecords + "&type=" + type";
```

> or something similar.